# How to check if an element exists inside a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python

For example, if I have a dictionary "dict" that contains 3 lists as values : `{1: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 2: ['D'], 3: ['Z']}`

How do I check if 'D' is an element inside any of the 3 lists inside the dictionary?

`'C' in dict.values()` doesn't work, which I think is because "dict" only contains lists as values, rather than letters.

Comment: You need to check each individual list; use `any('C' in v for v in dict.values())`

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten your dictionary values to a single list, and then check if `C` is in that flat list:

```
>>> 'C' in [x for i in my_dict.values() for x in i]
True
```